# How to connect a slot to signal QProcess::started() in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, signals, signals-slots

Edit: Solved.

Hi, I'm starting with Qt, I try to connect a slot to signal `QProcess::started()` but can't. `QObject::connect()` returns `false`.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Here's part of the code:

```
class foo : public QObject
{   
 public:
  QProcess *process;

 public slots:
  void process_started();
}

foo::foo()
{
 process = new QProcess();
 bool status = QObject::connect( process, SIGNAL( started() ), this, SLOT( process_started() ) );
 // status is false, meaning the slot and signal couldn't be connected
}
```

I know the process starts successfully because I tried `process->WaitForStarted()` and it returns `true`.
But I put a breakpoint at the slot `foo::process_started()` and it never gets hit.
What's the problem here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to put `Q_OBJECT` in your class declaration.  Without that keyword, `moc` doesn't know it needs to generate metaobject information for your class.